# opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp - incorrect set up?

Tags: apache, xampp, apache2

I'm new to linux (using ubuntu) and web servers in genearal and have run into some issues installing xampp. I want to install this to run apache, php and mysql. I believe these are running correctly because when I type

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

I'm alerted that apache, mysql and proFTPD are starting. I run the command again and get the notice that they're already running. When I type localhost into google chrome I get the xampp screen asking to select a language. I select this and nothing happens. I've attempted also installed apache2 so my opt/lampp location how contains htdocs and apache2. Inside htdocs is xampp. I believe the xampp server should be set up in xmapp/htdocs. Is it incorrect for xampp to be within htdcs? I'm really just stuck as to why the xampp wont open under local host. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since the xampp has been running, you can stop it:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

Or tried to restart by the CLI before it run or not:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

And you can visit this reference if you want to learn more about detail

Here're useful topics you maybe interest:

https://github.com/oliguo/Server-Deployment/blob/master/XAMPP.md

Answer (score 0):

Try giving permission to lang.tmp file

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/lang.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to install apache2 anymore when using xampp, it will crash with apache default xampp. try this to stop apache2:

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2
```

you can run xampp easily with:

```
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./yourXamppName.run
```

and finally you can put the php source code file, or html, or whatever it is in the **`htdocs`** directory in the **xampp** directory